# Which BIOS/CMOS Battery for ASRock FM2A75M-DGS?

Tags: motherboard, battery, cmos

Motherboard: ASRock FM2A75M-DGS

In order to change the CMOS battery of a friend's PC, can I use any CRC 2032 Li-Mn as replacement? Or do I need a special type?

The manual did not say exactly which battery is used, and I want to pre-order the battery before I open my friend's PC.

So are all CMOS batteries the same type, or do the vary for each Motherboard?

-- Edit --

My friend cannot open the PC and his place is too far away for me just to look by myself. The images of the MB I have found are not detailed enough to see the exact battery type. I looks like CRC 2032  to me [based on this flickr image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/htomari/32160758526).

So I wonder if it could be another type, or if I need to make sure a particular CRC 2032 technology.

Comment: What size battery are you using currently?

Comment: use the CRC 2032 Li-Mn you can get at Home Depot or a hardware store. I keep a couple of these in the cupboard.

Comment: Doesn't just anout every supermarket have them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CR2032 is one of the world's most common batteries - it's just one that many people are unaware of, compared to the AA or AAA for instance.

Any old CR2032 will do.
Depending on where you get them they're anything from $£€ 0.20 to $£€ 4.00 & there's very little difference. Avoid the BR2032 which are more rare & not a good replacement.

& here's your image, cropped, rotated & sharpened up a tad - showing nothing but a cheap-as-chips, no-name, CR2032…

[image]

As far as I'm aware, they're all Lithium/Manganese Dioxide - it's kind of part of the 'quality' spec. CR is the type, 2032 is the physical size, 2mm x 32mm

For an in-depth explanation [ty to Horst for the research] see https://www.master-instruments.com.au/files/knowledge-centre/engineering/guides-and-selection-charts/panasonic___selecting_the_right_lithium_battery_br_or_cr_series.pdf

Comment: Yup. Any supermarketthese days  will sell CR2032's. You have to look harder for the BR variant & it would be specified if that's what was needed. CR's are plentiful & cheap. Don't bother buying premium brands, it's not really economical. Sure, they might last 10 years instead of 8… by which time the computer is in the recycle anyway ;)

Comment: Understood, any CRC 2032 will do, and there is no better version of these batteries. I avoid BR and I just learnt what the difference is: https://www.master-instruments.com.au/files/knowledge-centre/engineering/guides-and-selection-charts/panasonic___selecting_the_right_lithium_battery_br_or_cr_series.pdf

Comment: Ah, nice find. I'll add that link to the end of my answer in case anyone really feels the need for the in-depth explanation.